# How to defer single tap gesture to superview

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am subclassing UITextFIeld. This textfield is contained within a UITableViewCell. I  want to catch a double-tap gesture but not a single-tap. The double tap enables editing (no problems there) and I want the single-tap to be passed to the cell to select the row.  
I am implementing this function by putting a view (doubleTapView) over the UITextfield and attaching the gesture recognizers to that view. When I want to start editing I hide this view and the TextView works as normal.

```
func addDoubleTapView() {
        doubleTapView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        addSubview(doubleTapView!)

        doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTap(_:)))
        doubleTapRecognizer?.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTapRecognizer?.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        doubleTapView?.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer!)

        singleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(singleTap(_:)))
        singleTapRecognizer?.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTapRecognizer!)
        singleTapRecognizer?.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTapRecognizer?.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        singleTapRecognizer?.delegate = self
        doubleTapView?.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer!)
    }

    func doubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        doubleTapView?.hidden = true
        doubleTapView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

I would like to ignore single taps but don’t see how to do this. I cannot use

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
```

because when the touch comes in I don’t yet know if it is a single-tap or the start of a double-tap. 
If there is a way to pass a single-tap gesture  up the responder chain I can’t find it. 

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Cliff

Comment: If you don't want to receive single taps, get rid of the single tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I omit the single tap recognizer the enclosing table view cell never receives the single tap gesture anyhow.

Comment: I have not understood what you are trying to do or why (it is very strange-sounding). But in general if you want a view in front to receive a double tap and a view behind to receive a single tap, then the view in front needs a double tap recognizer and the view behind needs a single tap recognizer.

Comment: I have a textfield in a tableview row. I want a single tap to select the row and a double tap to make the textfield editable. Since user interaction is enabled on the front view the single tap event does not get passed to the superview. I am looking for a way to have the superview receive a single tap. Does my explanation make sense?
Thanks,
Cliff

Comment: Not to me. If the user wants to make the text field editable, the user just taps in the text field. No special handling is needed. I don't see why you'd try to pervert the normal tap handling, which all users everywhere are used to. No one is going to know about or expect this secret double-tap trick.

Comment: The application is a live performance tool where the user quickly taps on rows to navigate. Since a single tap in a textfield normally invokes edit mode my choices are to either have a separate edit button or not allow tapping on the entire row to navigate.

Given a row with text across the entire row what is idea of standard edit behavior? I could of course implement swipe to the side to enable editing but was hoping for something a little more streamlined.